Kafka idempotent producers
According to the documentation, an idempotent kafka producer maintains a sequence number, ensuring deduplication of events and also, ordering.
Does this mean that within a single producer session, an idempotent kafka producer would indefinitely hang if it has successfully received ack for event with sequence 1 but due to some error, it is not able to produce event with sequence 2? Would events with sequence 3 and 4 not be consumed ever?

It depends on what Idempotent Producer sets the value of max.in.flight.requests.per.connection.
In earlier versions of Kafka it forces max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 which means event with sequence 2 will indefinitely hang because of INT.MAX retries.
In latest versions of Kafka
Idempotent Producer forces max.in.flight.requests.per.connection < 5,where events with sequence 3 and 4 are sent and order is internally maintained properly even later receiving event with sequence 2.

I don't think this is possible, since at the broker end, events are stored in an APPEND ONLY log file, reordering won't be possible.

In latest versions when max.in.flight.requests.per.connection < 5,it is mentioned that ordering is guaranteed internally.Kindly refer the "Guaranteed Message Ordering" section in below site.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kafka-idempotent-producer-rob-golder/

Even with max.in.flight.requests > 0 , if batch 1 is not written on KAFKA, the batch 2 will be rejected by KAFKA to conserve  ordering. So the answer is yes none of batch 2,3.. will b written in KAFKA until batch1 is done (reminder : we're talking for batches in same tpic partition) instead the idempotence config is useless

@ahmed.ettoumi Answer is with respect to single message which is asked in question where nothing stated about batch.In latest version,idempotent producer supports till max.in.flight.requests.per.connection < 5,where if events with sequences 3,4 are sent before 2...still kafka  manages proper order.

@OneCricketeer your views about the comments?
